# Laravel /PHP Getting the keys from an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, collections

I have a collection

```
Collection {#364 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        24 => Collection {#375 ▼
          #items: array:3 [▶]
        }
        0 => Collection {#376 ▶}
      ]
    }
```

I try and convert to an array grab the keys and sort them

```
dd(sort(array_keys($group_ids->toarray())));
```

I get the error **Only variables should be passed by reference**

I need to convert this collection to an array of the keys in ascending order.

```
dd(array_keys($group_ids->toArray()));
```

seems to give what I need but I cannot convert it.

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => 24
  1 => 0
]
```

Comment: You've several array/collections here.. which one you want to convert ?

Comment: You can get collection keys by using `->keys()` method iterate over your collection of collections and push it to an array or something

Comment: It is a typo sorry updated

Answer (score 1):

The `Only variables should be passed by reference` error is thrown because of the PHP's [sort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) function requires a reference and it can only be a variable not a return value from another function. To solve this error you can just use an intermediate variable like this:

```
$keys = array_keys($group_ids->toArray());
sort($keys);
```

Since you already using Laravel `Collection`, you can just use the [`keys()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-keys) and the [sort()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sort) methods instead. Suppose the `$group_ids` is an instance of `Collection`, you can extract the key and sort it ascendingly like this:

```
$sortedKeys = $group_ids->keys()->sort()->toArray();
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Below Solution is may be work for you.

When you call `User::all()` you get something like this:

```
0 => points: 10
1 => points: 50
2 => points: 30
3 => points: 70
4 => points: 20
```

What you can do is using the values() function, which will reset the keys of you collection:

```
0 => points: 70
1 => points: 50
2 => points: 30
3 => points: 20
4 => points: 10
```

May be you have try to sort data from the value. so key is automatically sorting out.

```
$users = User::all();
$users = $users->sortByDesc(function($item){
    return $item->points()->sum('amount');
})->values();
```

I am not sure about this solution but hope it helps little bit with your question. in your question i didn't see any query so i have no much how you generate that collections.

Thanks